# Как безопасно прочитать файл

Tags: c#, .net

Есть несколько способов прочитать информацию из файла. При этом, если файл занят другим процессом, то будет выброшено исключение.

Исключение конечно же можно перехватить, но если это недопустимо, что можно сделать?

Ситуация такая: используется `FileSystemWatcher` для чтения файла после изменения, изменение скорей всего будет сделано из блокнота. Если сразу после события об изменении попробовать прочитать файл, то его еще будет использовать процесс блокнота и он не успеет освободить доступ, мы получим исключение в большинстве случаев.

Для начала, хотелось бы понять, как можно проверить доступность на чтение файла, перед тем как его читать, что бы не ловить исключение.

Comment: Можно попробовать читать в цикле пока не прочитается, делая паузу после возникновения исключения.

Comment: А CreateFile с флагом "на чтение" не вернет ли Invalid handle, если файл еще занят и не может быть открыт?

Comment: Вы не можете никакими проверками узнать, будет ли доступен файл для чтения **к моменту, когда вы его откроете**. Исключений не избежать. Welcome to the real world.

Comment: Классика по теме: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не надо ставить перед собой задачу "чтобы не ловить исключение" - надо исключение поймать и повторить попытку.

Когда у меня была похожая задача, неплохо себя показала пауза в 100 миллисекунд после получения события до каких-либо действий с файлом - как правило, за это время файл успевал освободиться, пользователю же такая пауза обычно незаметна.

Comment: Да, тоже пытался так делать и это работало. Решил узнать менее топорные способы, но что-то мне подсказывает, что их нет.

Comment: я так понимаю в шарпе невозможно читать и писать файлы с блокировками из нескольких процессов, что норма для других языков?

Comment: @vitidev блокировка доступа к файлу обеспечивается операционной системой. Язык тут ни при чем.

Comment: @vitidev: Нигде не возможно. Файл на CD, после проверки CD вынули, исключение. Файл на сетевом диске, после проверки сервер отвалился, исключение. Файл на локальном диске, после проверки экаунт LOCAL SYSTEM переименовал файл, исключение. Вы никак не можете избежать отлова исключения, это вне контроля программиста.

Comment: @PavelMayorov в php например есть adviosory locking для файлов (LOCK_EX, LOCK_SH), что позволяет много читать и эксклюзивно писать и под винду тоже. И как подобное делать в с#? ReaderWriterLock  как бы совсем не то.

Comment: @vitidev [разумеется](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y973b725%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @PavelMayorov не уловил, что именно разумеется.  Если вы намекаете на FileShare, то непонятно как этим добиваться аналогичного пхп поведения.

Comment: @vitidev я не знаю какое поведение у `adviosory locking` в PHP - но C# позволяет сделать все что позволяет сделать Windows. PHP в принципе не может сделать больше на этой платформе.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я создам вопрос там все поймете

Comment: @PavelMayorov Прошу вас http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510186/c-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2