# c# блокировка файлов

Tags: c#, .net, файлы

В php есть возможность одновременного доступа к файлу с блокировками на запись LOCK_EX (экслюзивный доступ для записи) и на чтение LOCK_SH (общий доступ для чтения) Блокировка вызывается после открытия файла через flock

При вызове блокировки поведение зависит от типа блокировки. В общем то оно работает аналогично ReaderWriterLock и в c# для подобного поведения нужно использовать его. Однако ReaderWriterLock в c# работает в рамках одного процесса (и не относится непосредственно к файлам).

Более того windows будет мешать одновременному доступу к файлу с разных процессов.

В c# есть FileShare, но похоже, что это всего лишь разрешение другому процессу открывать файл на такой же тип доступа (из msdn не сильно понятно что но на самом деле)

Приведите пример как в c# сделать такое же поведение блокировки с общим файлом, как в php или его абстрактном аналоге ReaderWriterLock

**upd**: вижу требуется пояснение какое именно поведение ожидается
допустим есть несколько процессов которые почти одновременно хотят

1. читать
2. читать
3. читать
4. писать
5. читать
6. писать

Первые 3 получат разрешение на **одновременное** чтение. 4й подождет и получит блок для записи когда первые 3 отпустят файл. 5й будет ждать пока 4й не освободит, а 6й пока не освободит 5й

Так вот варианты  FileShare.ReadWrite или FileShare.Write никакой очереди не соблюдают (я проверил 2х писателей и у меня на выходе в файле каша). Они всего лишь указывают, что другой процесс может делать без выброса исключения. Но никак не защищают файлы от одновременной записи.

Если же поставить эксклюзивную блокировку без  FileShare, то другие процессы будут получать исключения, что мы и хотим избежать

**upd2:** и снова никто не понимает в чем проблема.

**Проблема**: много процессов, которые могут читать и писать в файл.

**Цель**: защитить общий файл от конкурентного доступа, дабы в один момент только один писатель мог писать. Не "запретить другим доступ",а  обеспечить **конкурирующий доступ**, когда много читателей может много читать одновременно, но писать только один, то есть то, для чего нужен ReaderWriterLock (не вижу я принципиальной разницы между ним и системой блокировки файлов в php)

Вариант "лови исключения и повторяй через 100мс до победного" не выдерживают критики. Писатель, который ждет пока файл освободится, может никогда не дождаться, потому что в эти 100мс куча читателей могут открыть файл для себя. 
Правильное решение - блокировка для чтения/записи ставится в очередь и в пхп (и не только в нем) это доступно из коробки,но в c# я не нашел как это делается.

Если сказать коротко,  то вопрос звучит так: **как сделать ReaderWriterLock  для файлов, которые шарятся между несколькими процессами?**

Comment: Где-то вы напутали. Судя по описанию поведения блокировок в PHP, оно совершенно **не** аналогично ReaderWriterLock

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну почему же. Вполне себе такое же - читатели друг другу не мешают, но стоит появится писателю и добраться до защищенной секции и заявить блокировку, то все читатели будут ждать. Не упадут с исключениями,а будут ждать

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю, что означает "одновременное получение двух блокировок". С ReaderWriterLock так сделать нельзя - пока кто-то получил блокировку на запись, остальные должны ждать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался в чате, чего же от меня хотелось.

С помощью пары FileAccess/FileShare нужного поведения не добиться. Требуемое поведение в WInAPI доступно через [`LockFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365203(v=vs.85).aspx), использование в C# можно увидеть тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784195/using-lockfileex-in-c-sharp

Comment: А почему не подходит просто `FileShare.Read` для читателей и `FileShare.None` для писателей? Объясните, чтобы и нам было понятно.

Comment: @VladD при FileShare.Read писателю придется ловить момент, чтобы влезть со своим FileShare.None. А это разве try..catch где в любой момент может влезть еще куча читателей, вместо того, чтобы стать в несуществующую очередь.

Comment: @VladD активный опрос против блокирующего либо асинхронного вызова. Плюс в LockFileEx сама заявка на эксклюзивную блокировку может заблокировать читателя - в то время как в подходе FileAccess/FileShare возможна ситуация "голодания".

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну да, активный опрос с экспоненциальными задержками, по-моему, вполне адекватен, учитывая, что ловить исключения и пытаться переоткрыть файл всё равно придётся (временный сбой сетевого диска? медленное распознавание системой флешки?)

Comment: @vitidev: Ну, да, race, но поскольку у нас несколько процессов, то никто в любом случае не гарантирует «справедливое распределение» права на блокировку. У нас же не RTOS.

Comment: @VladD ну...как сказать. в php/ruby такой проблемы нет, в том числе и под виндой. Там  не нужно в цикле дергать файл и проверять. Просто ничего подобного не реализовали в .NET

Comment: @vitidev: В руби нету потому, что проблема игнорируется. В реальном мире исключений/ошибок при работе с файлами избежать невозможно. По поводу **правильного** дизайна: зачем давать всего лишь ожидание разблокировки, тогда уже нужно и ожидание появления файла по данному пути? И что делать, если уже открытый и заблокированный файл исчез? (А про дизайн PHP давайте вообще говорить не будем.)

Comment: @VladD проблема starvation циклом не решается

Comment: @VladD проблема отсутствия файла решается созданием пустого

Comment: @VladD "правильный" дизайн пхп не имеет никакого отношения к проблеме. Требование блокировать файл происходит в любой момент **после** удачного открытия файла. Это всего лишь реализация ReaderWriterLock для файлов. И она консультативная, то есть работает там, где ее хотят использовать. Не вижу в ее реализации ничего неправильного. К  тому же там есть возможность try lock

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Да, starvation циклом не решается. Мой тезис состоит в том, что эта проблема _вовсе_ не решается. // Проблема отсутствия файла так решается далеко не всегда. Например, в случае недоподключенной флешки, у вас отсутствует даже диск.

Comment: @vitidev: Окей, вернёмся назад. Что происходит в руби при попытке открытия файла, если (1) файла нету, (2) файл есть, но заблокирован? (Следующий вопрос будет «И почему эти вещи разные?».)

Comment: @VladD Давайте в пхп (в руби это тоже есть, но именно в пхп я использую это постоянно). 1 При открытии файла будет обработан флаг открытия файла r/w/a/x/c и файл либо будет создан либо будет ошибка. 2 Будет, что и 1 (блокировка то консультативная)

Comment: @vitidev поправка - в Windows нет консультативных блокировок. Все блокировки (в том числе используемые PHP) - принудительные.

Comment: @PavelMayorov что не мешает пхп использовать эту систему на вин ). не забывайте мой главный вопрос. Потому я и задал вопрос как с учетом всех ограничений, что дает ось замудрить ReaderWriterLock для файлов ибо try_catch не лезет ни в какие ворота. Я могу разрешить процессам читать писать...но не могу использовать что то вида ReaderWriterLock

Comment: @vitidev: Не совсем понимаю, что есть консультативная блокировка. Давайте уточню — пусть у нас такие флаги, которые запрещают создание файла, и требуют его открыть. И две ситуации: (1) Файла, а также каталога, нету, (2) Файл есть, но он заблокирован. В каком из случаев вызов будет ждать, пока файл станет доступен (появится/разблокируется)?

Comment: @VladD Консультативная значит, что она будет работать только для тех, кто ее использует явно. **Дополнительный** инструмент для организации параллельного доступа. Ни в каком случае он не будет ждать. Открытие файла это открытие, а просьба установить блокировку (на которую реагируют только те, кто тоже решил использовать блокировки) - другое

Comment: @vitidev: То есть, если блокировка уже есть, то файл **будет всё равно открыт**? Это какая-то странная блокировка, раз её кто угодно может проигнорировать.

Comment: @VladD да. в php файлы не блокируются по умолчанию (и было бы удивительно если бы было иначе в силу самой природы задач), но если нужен конкурентный доступ, то можно уведомить других (тех кто использует тот же механизм), что нужна блокировка. Блокировка для чтения блокирует блокирует писателей. Блокировка для записи блокирует всех. Они не отбиваются с ошибкой, а становятся в очередь ожидания. Те, кто механизм не использует, никаких ограничений не испытывают. Нужно - используешь. Не нужно - не используешь. удобно.

Comment: @VladD Лучше уйти в чат, но я не знаю как, а система не предлагает.

Answer (score 6):

Поведение, аналогичное описанному в PHP:

```
File.Open(path, mode, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read)
```

Эта команда открывает файл для чтения-записи, и при этом разрешает открывать файл для чтения другим процессам (тем самым удерживая блокировку записи).

```
File.Open(path, mode, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
```

Эта команда, наоброт, открывает файл для чтения - и при этом разрешает другим процессам как ситать его, так и записывать.

---

Поведение, аналогичное ReaderWriterLock:

```
File.Open(path, mode, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
```

Это - эксклюзивная блокировка файла, с открытием его в режиме чтения-записи.

```
File.Open(path, mode, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
```

Это - неэксклюзивная блокировка файла, с открытием его в режиме чтения.

---

Ну и остались нерассмотренными еще 14 комбинаций :)

Comment: А что будет если 2 процесса хотят получить блокировку на запись? Будут ли они писать одновременно или же станут в очередь? в msdn этот вопрос не освещен

Comment: Зависит от того, что вы понимаете "блокировкой на запись".

Comment: В приведенных мною примерах операции открытия файла на запись - эксклюзивные, поскольку запрещают запись для других.

Comment: Я понимаю что есть файл и открывать на чтение его могут одновременно сколько угодно. Потом появляется писатель который заявляет эксклюзивную блокировку с целью записать и его запрос становится в очередь и когда доходит наконец до файла, то файл блокируется. Все новые читатели и писатели становятся в очередь и ждут пока писатель не освободит файл. Тут не нужно проверять с исключениями "доступен ли файл для такой операции" и 2 писателя отработают друг за другом, а не одновременно. Собственно вопрос FileShare.ReadWrite дает такое же поведение?

Comment: Нет. FileShare.ReadWrite - это наоборот, отсутствие блокировки.

Comment: Тогда я не вижу ответа на свой основной вопрос. Как должен быть описан вариант позволяющий получить эксклюзивную блокировку для записи, чтобы другой процесс желающий получить такую же блокировку просто ждал пока первый процесс освободит? При этом разумеется читатели тоже могут заявлять желание заблокировать. FileShare, как я понял, всего лишь разрешение/запрет другим процессам, но не имеют отношения к вышеописанным блокировкам для чтения и записи "много читателей, но только один писатель за раз"

Comment: @vitidev у меня все написано.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37977/discussion-between-vitidev-and-pavel-mayorov).